# How to add content to template dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-socket-io

I am using `socket.io` in my project. When a user post a request to server, an `emit` event will be sent (broadcasted) from the server to all connected sockets. The `emit` will send all the new requests available in the database to the client (to be displayed to the user).

I am looping through a static variable (`StaffScreenComponenet.allRequests`) inside `staff-screen.component.html`:

```
   <mat-grid-list cols="4">
        <div *ngFor="let request of retrieveRequests()">
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <app-list-requests tableName="{{request.tableName}}" requestType="{{request.requestType}}" date="{{request.createdAt}}"></app-list-requests>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        </div>

   </mat-grid-list>
```

I have another method (below code) that prints the value received from the server to the console but the content in the html is not reflecting the actual content in `StaffScreenComponent.allRequests`. In other words, I can see that `StaffScreenComponent.allRequests` length increased but the new values in `StaffScreenComponent.allRequests` are not displayed in HTML.

```
  retrieveRequests(){
    console.log(StaffScreenComponent.allRequests)
    return StaffScreenComponent.allRequests;
  }
```

The component `ts` file code is below:

```
export class StaffScreenComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  longText = `The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog
  from Japan. A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was
  originally bred for hunting.`;

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private webSocketService: WebSocketService, private socket: Socket) {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log('test');
    changes['allRequests'].firstChange;
    console.log(changes['allRequests'].currentValue)
  }

  public static allRequests: any;
  @Input()
  check: any;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3000/api/getRequests').subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      StaffScreenComponent.allRequests = res;

     
    });
    this.socket.on('fetchRequests', (data: string) => {
      console.log('checking')
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  retrieveRequests(){
    console.log(StaffScreenComponent.allRequests)
    return StaffScreenComponent.allRequests;
  }

}
```

And the service file `` code below:

```
export class WebSocketService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  // emit event
    fetchRequests(requestMdel: AddRequestModel) {
        this.socket.emit('fetchRequests', requestMdel);
    } 

    // listen event
    OnFetchRequests() {
        return this.socket.fromEvent('fetchRequests');
    }

    setupSocketConnection(){
        this.socket.on('fetchRequests', (data: string) => {
            console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem('allRequests', JSON.stringify(data[0]));
            StaffScreenComponent.allRequests = data;
          });
    }
}
```

And the component that include the section of the code that changes the `StaffScreenComponent.allRequests` is below:

```
export class ItemDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  allRequests: any;

  @Input()
  name: string = '';

  @Input()
  _id: string = '';

  requestTypes = {
    waiter: "waiter",
    bill: "bill"
  }

  constructor(private itemsAPIService: ItemsApiService, private webSocketService: WebSocketService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.webSocketService.setupSocketConnection();
  }

  onRequest(requestType: string, tableName: string){
    // console.log(requestType + ' / ' + tableName);
    let requestModel = new AddRequestModel(tableName, requestType);
    this.itemsAPIService.submitRequest(requestModel);

    this.webSocketService.fetchRequests(requestModel);
    // this.webSocketService.setupSocketConnection();
    console.log(StaffScreenComponent.allRequests);
  }
}
```

**How can I render the content in the `html` again after it is being created?**

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine the problem.

Comment: @MikeOne I edited the last line of the question to try and clarify my question more

Comment: That doesn’t help. We need to know how you are getting your messages from the socket? I’m not seeing any observable code or any logic in your question. Show the component code and the socket service maybe?

Comment: @MikeOne I have updated the question with further details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using OnPush ChangeDetection? If yes, you have to inject changedetectorref and run markforcheck once the value are updated.

Comment: I am not aware of these features to be honest, will read about them now

Comment: I looked up OnPush and ChangeDetection and managed to resolve my issue after understanding them. Upvote and accept answer, thank you!